# Validation framework in REST web service using CXF

Tags: java, web-services, validation, rest, cxf

I am new to Web services and Apache CXF.

Can you please let me know whether CXF provides its own validation framework for REST/SOAP to validate incoming request for URL , path or header parameters before actually calling the API (f yes, how shall I go about implementing it?) or do I need to do the validation stuff in my own custom Interceptor that I wrote ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What kind of validation are you talking about?

Comment: Just like Struts2. XML based. I want to make an xml defining the properties (that I get in URL,headers, etc) and the rules. So that when the request comes to the controller, It will perform that validation, If successful, then the API is called, else, error code is sent back to the client

Comment: *What* do you validate? Against which rules?

Comment: @Tichodroma Things to validate --> path parameters, header parameters in REST request.  Rules --> null check, regex match, empty check, etc etc

Comment: Just use interceptors. They are provided precisely for that reason. You can configure them to run at the phase suitable for your application .

Comment: @nadirsaghar Hmm.. I was wondering what would be the right choice to do the validation. Is it Custom Interceptor or Custom Request Handler?

Comment: Interceptors. I would use RequestHandler to register custom Input types.

Answer (score 0):

the CXF validation framework is extensive.

[cxf validation here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/validationfeature.html)

no need to customise interceptors, just config validators.

-lp